# SSAS Cube excel pivot table display as list rather than groups

Tags: sql, excel, pivot, ssas, cube

How do I to create a detail list report (not summary/grouped report).

So for example, display all the values in a list rather than grouping it together and having to expand it.

Thanks.

Comment: It depends on your version of Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Action in SSAS to drillthrough to the detail list.

This may help [Drillthrough](http://www.simple-talk.com/content/print.aspx?article=981)